# Connecting two pieces of metal curtain rod

Tags: curtain-rail

I have a curtain rod that has become disconnected in the middle. I am trying to figure out what kind of connector is used to join the two pieces of the curtain rod. There appears to be some kind of insert within each rod with threads.

Here is a photo of the curtain rod:

[image: curtain rod]

And here is the other side of the curtain rod.
[image: Other side of curtain rod]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How about a picture of the other piece of rod.

Comment: I added a picture of the other piece of the rod.  My question is what kind of connector can I use to reattach the rods to each other?

Comment: I should also add that the two sides of the rod are the same size.  There does not appear to be a way to insert one side of the rod into the other, which is why I assume there must been some kind of connector.

Answer (score 1):

NEW info considering to your images...

** Your type of closet rod **

Your bar is horizontally held in place by a set screw which is located on the underside of the holder.

If the bar cannot reach two holders or walls to hold each end, then the rod cannot be held into position.

** A different type of closet rod **

Yes, there is a threaded insert. The insert of lobed.

- Insert the smaller rod (with the insert) into the bigger rod.
- Turn the small rod clockwise to tighten so that the small rod will not longer side in or out of the bigger rod.
- Turn the small rod counter-clockwise to loosen.
- After you understand, insert the rod into the closet, expand to desired length, and tighten.

Note: Do not over tighten or it will be very difficult to loosen and/or you may break/reshape the insert or the larger pipe. This is not a connection which slowly tightens. You will discover that the tight/loose difference is only about 1/4 turn.

Comment: Yes, I saw the threads too. You shall remove the rod on the first photo to expose the male part.